# Rails Remote JSON call blocking controller thread

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing an HTTP request against a remote API in my controller such as this:

```
@results= JSON.load(open("http://someendpoint/whatever.json"))
```

I am then rendering the contents of the response in my view by iterating over the structure provided in the response:

```
<% @results['result'].each do |result| %>$
```

This works 100% fine from a technical standpoint.  The problem is that the initial JSON load in the controller appears to block the controller's thread (prior to rendering the page). There is additional information on the page that I would like to load quickly (i.e. without the controller thread blocking).  Basically what I'd like to do is make the HTTP request asynchronously, and then render the JSON structure via callback.  I can put the information in a partial if that would make things easier.

I can definitely use something like an XMLHttpRequest to concatenating the results of this (with interpolated HTML elements) into a string, and then just using DOM insertion methods to place the data into the view.  So, I suppose my questions are this:

Is there a good way to do this asynchronously, for example by using a Javascript a callback to render a partial from a variable declared in an XMLHttpRequest?  Is it bad to declare variables in the view and then render them in a partial?  This just seems like bad design to me.   I basically don't want to generate a long HTML string after an XHR request and inject it into the DOM because it seems 'sloppy'.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it not be simpler to put @results in it's own controller action with it's own endpoint and load it via AJAX?